# Call a state of another script

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state, call

hello guys I have the script **App.js** that is running in the entire application and has my page to react navigation (drawer) that is **Screen3.js**

I want to call my state **speed**. from App.js to Screen3.
my speed are changing every **10 seconds**.

**App.js**

```
import Screen1 from './pages/Screen1';
import Screen2 from './pages/Screen2';
import Screen3 from './pages/Screen3';
import CustomSidebarMenu from './CustomSidebarMenu';

global.currentScreenIndex = 0;

class NavigationDrawerStructure extends Component {

    toggleDrawer = () => {
        //Props to open/close the drawer
        this.props.navigationProps.toggleDrawer();
    };

    constructor(props) {

        super(props)

        this.state = {

            speed: ''
        }

          and rest script
```

**Screen3.js**

````
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { SectionList, FlatList, View, Text, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet, Image, PermissionsAndroid, ActivityIndicator, Platform, TouchableOpacity, List, Drawer, Container, Header, Content } from 'react-native';
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';
import { App } from '../App'

export default class Screen3 extends Component {

    render() {
        return (

            <View style={styles.MainContainer}>

              <Text style={{ fontSize: 23 }}> My Screen {global.currentScreenIndex + 1} </Text>
                <Text style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 16 }}>
                    myspeed: {App.this.props.speed} //< --- MY PROBLEM HERE <---!!
                </Text>

            </View>

        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    MainContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: 20,
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: 50,
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});
```
````

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of options available if you wanted to maintain some global values.

1. **Redux**

   Store that parameter in redux store and connect your component wherever you need it.
2. **Event Listener**

   You can use `NativeEventEmitter` and pass value along with that call. Now add that event listener to the component where you need updated value and that's it.
3. **Global state**

   Store value in App level state and pass it along with all the child, but I will not prefer this option as this parameter will be passed to other components also where it is not actually required.

Comment: And  context Api

Comment: @DevAS Oh yes, forgot it. I have not worked on it enough so not sure how it works.

Comment: if i use redux after reading the converter all scipts to native?

Comment: if i use redux then will i have to convert to native? all my scripts?

Comment: redux does not have any connection with native. It is javascript/node thing

Comment: You can help with script of NativeEventEmitter? I wanna use react native yet

Answer (score 0):

Pass state like this from **App.js** component

```
<App speed={this.state.speed}/>
```

and access like this in your **Screen3** component

```
<Text style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 16 }}>
         myspeed: {this.props.speed} 
 </Text>
```

> Note- As you are accessing that isn't the way to access state from
>   parent to child component.

If you don't want to pass state(speed) like this then use context Api for that so that you could access where ever you want.